# Prisma splice Item from Array

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I have been pushing updates to an array and was wondering if there is a built-in method to remove an entry from the array as well. Basically reversing the push command. I suspect that I have to query all documents and remove the item myself. But maybe there is some functionality I was unable to find inside the documentation.

**Push**:

```js
 const addTag = await prisma.post.update({
   where: {
     id: 9,
   },
   data: {
     tags: {
       push: 'computing',
     },
   },
 })
```

**Remove Expectation**:

```js
 const removeTag = await prisma.post.update({
   where: {
     id: 9,
   },
   data: {
     tags: {
       splice: 'computing',
     },
   },
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing, there's no method to splice/remove items from a scalar list using Prisma. You would have to fetch the scalar list from your database, modify it manually in your application code and overwrite the record in your database with an `update` operation.

There is a [feature request for this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7401), please feel free to follow/comment with your use-case to help us track demand for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { dogs } = await prisma.user.findOne({
  where: {
    id: userId
  },
  select: {
    dogs: true
  },
});

await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    id: userId
  },
  data: {
    dogs: {
      set: dogs.filter((id) => id !== 'corgi'),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: And for updateMany?